# I want to know how to this curlup page effect on xcode

Tags: xcode, curl, page-curl

[image]

Please see above screen shot. I want to know how can I do effect like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).
This is a native ViewController called UIPageViewController. There are plenty of tutorials on the net.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only animation effect then not exact but similar effect you can get:

```
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationCurl" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:NO];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Otherwise you must need to take -

- Page-Based Application which contains UIPageViewController

As far i know